# Cypress check what is logged in console

Tags: cypress

I have to make a test where I checked that something is logged in the console when I click on an element, let's call this mrv.close. Since this is not a window event I am not sure how I should check this? I've tried with stubs and using cy.win() but it doesn't work. How can I check what is logged in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an idea [here](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#How-do-I-spy-on-console-log):

```js
cy.visit('/', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.stub(win.console, 'log').as('consoleLog')
  },
})

cy.get('@consoleLog').should('be.calledWith', 'Hello World!')
```